# YouTube "Refused to display video in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: video, youtube

This page has been working in the past, and today I discovered that videos now fail to load.  There is a video which should load at the top of the page.
http://coaching.southwesternconsulting.com/Sales_Coaching_and_Leadership_Coaching.aspx?

The console shows an error:

> Refused to display
>   'http://www.youtube.com/error?ytsession=0o8pO-b9SnuPUaZvjK_Nz3utizu6JgHmPuaR…WEpL97aAghVBkkJZaJ-Sr1t-8clf5ZoIcmd1odA59l77QyRTg1Yt98HysFkauNwa7ewDK8I6ec'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Markup for the video looks like this.

```
<iframe height="298" width="397" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vekBokmx124?wmode=transparent&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Other answers in StackOverflow show the URL needs to be formatted as follows:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid
... which is what I'm doing.

What do I need to change here to make this work? Thanks.